# Computer freezes randomly and rarely - how to troubleshoot

Tags: hardware-failure, freeze, crash, troubleshooting

Assembled my computer myself in 2019 with these parts:

```
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X Six-Core Processor 3.60 GHz
Graphics card: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060 6GB
Power supply: Corsair RM750X 750W v2
SSD: Crucial MX500 500GB 2.5"
RAM: Corsair 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4 3000MHz CL15 Vengeance LPX
Motherboard: B450 GAMING PRO CARBON AC (MS-7B85)
```

It worked completely fine with no errors at all up until 2022, when I bought 2 additional ram sticks with the exact same model as before. So I had 4x8gb, with the new ones in one channel and the old ones in the old other channel. I realized in hindsight that even though it is the same model, they might not be compatible.

**Issue**:
Initially it worked, but ever since then I have had rare and random crashes where the computer freezes and does not respond at all and I have to turn it off. The screen is still on and a sound loop plays of the last 0.5 seconds of sound and then just static, but sometimes no sound. This happens on both linux and windows and seem to happen more when gaming or using a lot of resources, but it can happen at doing nothing as well. It has also happened if I e.g. slam my fist / mouse into the table or if I accidentally touch / knock my computer. It also seems to happen in clusters, e.g. if it happens once and I restart my computer, it usually happens 5-10 more times around 5 minutes after restarting. And sometimes when restarting, the computer starts but the screens, mouse and keyboard does not "get activated", i.e. does not recognize that the computer has turned on. Sometimes a crash does not happen in months, other periods it happens several times a week.

Initially, I strongly believed it was the ram upgrade that was causing the issues, but then I removed by newly bought ram sticks, and it still continues to happen regardless if 16gb ram (old), 16gb ram (new) or 32gb ram (both). I ran the windows 10 memory diagnostics tool and it returned no problems, but I remember running a benchmark before where it said the ram didnt have optimal settings in bios, but it wasnt a problem. I'm glad that the 32gb ram setup does not seem to be the issue so that I can use what I bought, but I need to figure out what the issue is. **What could be the issue or how would I go about troubleshooting this? Is there any program to test it automatically?**

Comment: Reseat all your other RAM chips

Comment: @JanDoggen Can you explain that? I don't understand what that is or how to do it

Comment: Take them out and put them back in. Maybe with other chips as well.

Comment: really sounds like a loose connection (power maybe) since it is triggered by physical jostling.

Comment: @FrankThomas Hmm, you're right. But would that cause the screen to freeze but still display image? Would it not turn black? I will check the cables

Comment: well, that might imply something other than power. just out of curiousity, when this happens, does the numlock light on the keyboard still change state if you toggle it?

Comment: @FrankThomas I don't know about that. However, if I spam press keys I hear the "beep" windows sound.

Comment: ok that does imply that the system is still on and processing input from the device at least at the kernel. when the kernel is hard-locked, it won't be able to process numlock state change or object to keys being pressed. hmm.

Answer (score 1):

First get a program to monitor your voltages 3.3v,5v, and 12v from your motherboards internal sensors.  Also the temperatures.  Maybe MSI Afterburner?

Then stress test the components.
For the CPU I recommend, Prime95  Does your system freeze after running Prime 95 for a couple hours?  Also monitor the voltages while it is running, they need to be within 5% of the rated voltage.

Then FurMark for the GPU

Can it run for an hour without issue?

How is the heat and voltage levels while the tests are running?

Also chkdsk /r on your storage hdd or ssd

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out and report back

Comment: I have used Prime95 and FurMark and there was no freeze and no problems whatsoever. The temperature is fine and the voltages, as far as I can tell, are also fine, but I don't know much about that. 

I have always had XAMP off, but I tried enabling it, and the crashes were more predictable and more "violent" now (e.g. more and louder static noise) and the screen turns off. I am assuming there is a problem with the motherboard and I saw it has not been updated since 2019, so I will try to do a BIOS update.